# Notepad ++ объединить ячейки в csv разделенные ;

Tags: регулярные-выражения, notepad++

есть csv вида:

```html
00000004924;город, улица, дом, квартира, 1;0423;8460.78;Иванов;Иван;Писечкин;89030000080
00000004802;город, улица, дом, квартира, 2;0423;-10.42;Петров;Петька;Камушкин;89260000050
```

как можно через регулярки объединить ФИО в одну ячейку?

```html
00000004924;город, улица, дом, квартира, 1;0423;8460.78;Иванов Иван Владимирович;89030000080
00000004802;город, улица, дом, квартира, 2;0423;-10.42;Петров Петька Камушкин;89260000050
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Применительно к таким строкам можно предложить вот такую регулярку

```
(?<=[а-я]);(?!\d|$)
```

Найденное менять на пробел...

```js
const re = /(?<=[а-я]);(?!\d|$)/g

let s = '00000004924;город, улица, дом, квартира, 1;0423;8460.78;Иванов;Иван;Писечкин;89030000080'
console.log(s.replace(re, ' '))
s = '00000004924;город, улица, дом, квартира, 1;0423;8460.78;Иванов;Иван;Писечкин;'
console.log(s.replace(re, ' '))
```

Comment: Спасибо друг! в notepad++ только нужно вставить **(?<=[а-я]);(?!\d)**

Comment: Не подскажешь как быть в такой ситуации 00000004924;город, улица, дом, квартира, 1;0423;8460.78;Иванов;Иван;Писечкин;тут нет номера телефона и получается csv ломается из-за отсутствия ; где должен быть номер. пулучаю 00000004924;город, улица, дом, квартира, 1;0423;8460.78;Иванов Иван Писечкин

Comment: @mousesport, немного поменял регулярку - теперь обрабатывает оба варианта "с числом" и "без числа"...